# How do i save the image result from this code?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to write a code that identifies the eyes of parakeets. So far, i have managed to use a code that identifies the circles edges and got great results at a certain threshold. But i can't save the result image.

I've tried using `imwrite('result.png', clone)` to save the result at the end of the code, but when I run it I'm get `TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'.`
I need the clone image to be colored too, but I've no idea where to start.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

def nothing(x): 
pass

# Load an image 
img = cv2.imread('sample.png')

# Resize The image
if img.shape[1] > 600:
img = imutils.resize(img, width=600)

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('Treshed')

# create trackbars for treshold change
cv2.createTrackbar('Treshold','Treshed',0,255,nothing)


while(1):

# Clone original image to not overlap drawings
clone = img.copy()

# Convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(clone, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get current positions of four trackbars
r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Treshold','Treshed')

# Thresholding the gray image
ret,gray_threshed = cv2.threshold(gray,r,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Blur an image
bilateral_filtered_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_threshed, 5, 175, 175)

# Detect edges
edge_detected_image = cv2.Canny(bilateral_filtered_image, 75, 200)

# Find contours
contours, _= cv2.findContours(edge_detected_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    # approximte for circles
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if ((len(approx) > 8) & (area > 30) ):
        contour_list.append(contour)

# Draw contours on the original image
cv2.drawContours(clone, contour_list,  -1, (255,0,0), 2)

# there is an outer boundary and inner boundary for each eadge, so contours double
print('Number of found circles: {}'.format(int(len(contour_list)/2)))

#Displaying the results     
cv2.imshow('Objects Detected', clone)
cv2.imshow("Treshed", gray_threshed)

# ESC to break
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this modification and it works flawlessly.

```
# ESC to break
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    cv2.imwrite('result.png', clone)
    break
```

[image: sample.jpg]
[image: result.png]

There's either a misconception about when/where to call imwrite or something is messy with your python/opencv version. I ran it in pycharm using python 3.6.8 and opencv-python 4.0.0.21

Comment: Thank you! I think i was calling imwrite earlier than i should. Is there a way to print only the contourned area in the eye? I'm really struggling with that.

Comment: That's a different questions but for a simple solution:
    1. check for a _roundish_ shape. Delete every contour [with a concave shape](http://i.imgur.com/2EcLOmr.png). Leave only convex ones.
   2. delete every countour apart from the largest one regarding covered area.

For a sophisticated / stable approach [train a neural network](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API) for parakeet eyes

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look at it. You've really helped me a lot!